# Django renew field from database,calculated field in Database

Tags: python, django, field

Newby in django, have two question, can't find needed info.

1) I have database (SQLite) which have table scale_calibration and field weight. Other application rewrite value in field weight 1-2 times per second. Is there possibility in Django to renew this field without renew browser (F5)?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Calibration(models.Model):
mean_weight = models.FloatField(editable=True)
hours_to_export = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=4, editable=True)
weight = models.FloatField(editable=True)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Calibration
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Calibration)
```

2) I try follow [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805303/django-model-method-or-calculation-as-field-in-database) to make easy calculated field (that will be write to database when save), but i have no results and no error, don't understand where i did mistake.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Calibration(models.Model):
    mean_weight = models.FloatField(editable=True)
    hours_to_export = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=4, editable=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(editable=True)
    calibration_factor = models.FloatField(editable=True)
    @property
    def get_calibration(self):
        return self.weight/self.mean_weight


def save(self, *args, **kwarg):
        self.calibration_factor = self.get_calibration()
        super(Calibration, self).save(*args, **kwarg)
```

Please help with advise.

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX

Answer (score 0):

As @david-alford mention, AJAX is a good solution to your problem. This simply writing JavaScript in your templates that make a request every `n` seconds and update your webpage, also you will need a new endpoint in your Django app that provides the update values from your model to this requests to be repeated.

If this sounds weird or complicated, take a look at some [AJAX examples with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html), and feel free to ask more specific questions for clarifications.