# Calculate Age in Django Model with database connection

Tags: python, django

I have seen many examples of calculating age in a django model ([such as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805303/django-model-method-or-calculation-as-field-in-database)). However, most do not have a connection to a database and are simply empty models to be used in pushing to a database. To simplify my example, I have a django model of records of people connected to a SQL Server. I want to, when I query from the DB, also calculate the current age of the person. If I call `age` in my view, I get the following error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'age' into field`

How can I do this, even though age is not a current database field?

```
class Person(model.Model)
     personid = models.IntegerField(db_column='PersonId', primary_key=True)
     birth_date = models.DateField(db_column='DOB')

     @property
     def get_age(self):
         return relativedelta(self.birth_date.days, datetime.date.now()).years

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.age = self.get_age()
         super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: doesnt work ***`person_instance.get_age`***?

Comment: get `query set has no operation get_age`

Comment: I said `person_instance`, not *Person QuerySet*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: `Person.objects.get(id=12345).get_age`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes, but I dont want for just one instance. I want for a larger query.

Comment: Checkout this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410078/calculate-age-in-django-model-with-database-connection?noredirect=1#comment108635959_61410488)