# Updating Cart in Django Admin on adding and removing items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following models in my application in which I add items to a cart and can remove them too. The adding and removing of a cart item has been achieved through my views but what i want is that about how can I do this in Admin.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price=models.IntegerField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    cust_id=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total=models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Cart_Item(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    cart=models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want to achieve in Admin is that that if I add or remove a `Cart_Item` object in Admin, it should update the corresponding values of `count` and `total` in `Cart` accordingly for that particular user

Answer (score 2):

I would consider `count` and `total` to be [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) of `Cart`, like this:

### Solution 1

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price=models.IntegerField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    cust_id=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Model Property
    @property
    def count(self):
        return Cart_Item.objects.filter(cart=self).count()
    @property
    def total(self):
        return Cart_Item.objects.filter(cart=self).item.aggregate(Sum('price'))
class Cart_Item(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    cart=models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can then access the count and total just like you would access any other field, like this:

```
cart = Cart(cust_id=user)
items_in_cart = cart.items
total_balance = cart.amount
```

### Solution 2

We can also use the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) attribute of the model to access the children or "access the model backward":

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price=models.IntegerField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    cust_id=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Model Property
    @property
    def count(self):
        return self.cart_items.count()
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.cart_items.item.aggregate(Sum('price'))
class Cart_Item(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    cart=models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cart_items')
```

### Why Model Methods?

We need model methods because `count` and `total` are being generated dynamically. 
If you really would like the model methods to be fields of Cart, you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805303/django-model-method-or-calculation-as-field-in-database).


Please comment if this doesn't work, I'm new to Django.

Comment: Do you think if I add a new Cart_item in admin then it will reflect the changes in `Cart`

Comment: I think it will, it should change the `amount` and `total` variables accordingly

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Please let me know so i can edit or change

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It throws me error on accessing the model in my admin.

Comment: I figured out a way to achieve it with some modifications. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh. Good luck on your app!